# SQL Server : sync tables from different databases

Tags: sql-server, data-synchronization

I have two SQL Server databases, let's says `DB1` and `DB2`.

- DB1 [table1, table2, table3]
- DB2 [table2, table4, table5]

Is it possible for me to sync table2 from DB1 with table2 from DB2 only?
I don't want to sync all the databases.

Comment: Sure no problem at all. Look into replication.

Comment: one-time or ongoing?  one-time, SQL Data Compare; on-going, replication, as @SeanLange says.

Comment: @user1443098 on-going. Thank you, I will check